# Composición en java

Tags: java

Mi duda es la siguiente, estoy aplicando Composicion en un proyecto en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) que trata acerca de una aplicacion academica donde tengo varias clases:

*Asignatura
*Programa
*Grupo
*Semestre

El problema es el siguente, el enunciado nos dice: El profesor recibe las cargas académicas de las asignaturas de las que es responsable. La carga, contiene los siguientes datos de la asignatura (Programa, sede, Semestre academico y Grupo ).

El codigo que implemente es el siguiente:

```
public class Grupo {

private String codigo;
private int numeroGrupo, numeroEstudiantes, jornada, maximo;
private ArrayList<Estudiante> estudiantes;


public Grupo(String codigo, int numeroGrupo, int numeroEstudiantes, int jornada, ArrayList<Estudiante> 
estudiantes) {
this.codigo = codigo;
this.numeroGrupo = numeroGrupo;
this.numeroEstudiantes = numeroEstudiantes;
this.jornada = jornada;
this.maximo = 25;
this.estudiantes = estudiantes;

//Metodos getter y setter......
}
}

public class Semestre {


private int numeroSemestre;
private int maximoCreditos;
private int minimoCreditos;


public Semestre(int numeroSemestre, int maximoCreditos, int minimoCreditos) {
this.numeroSemestre = numeroSemestre;
this.maximoCreditos = maximoCreditos;
this.minimoCreditos = minimoCreditos;

//Metodos getter y setter......
}
}

public class Programa {

private String campus;
private String nombre;
private int numeroCreditos;
private String tipo;

public Programa(String campus, String nombre, int numeroCreditos, String tipo) {
this.campus = campus;
this.nombre = nombre;
this.numeroCreditos = numeroCreditos;
this.tipo = tipo;


//Metodos getter y setter......
}
```

Entonces lo que quiero saber si en la clase Asignatura implemente bien la composicion al declarar el Nombre del programa de tipo Programa, el grupo de tipo Grupo y semestre academico de tipo Semestre.
Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

```
public class Asignatura implements Serializable, Academico {


private String codigo;
private String nombre;
private int numeroCreditos;
private Programa programa;
private Grupo grupo;
private Semestre semestreAcademico;

public Asignatura(String codigo, String nombre, int numeroCreditos, Semestre semestre, Programa programa, 
Grupo grupo) {

this.codigo = codigo;
this.nombre = nombre;
this.numeroCreditos = numeroCreditos;
this.programa = programa;
this.grupo = grupo;
this.semestreAcademico = semestre;


//Metodos getter y setter......

}
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta parece bien estructurada, pero no termino de entender bien tu duda. Lo que si te comento, es que no estas programando en netbeans. Estas programando en java, netbeans es solo la herramienta (ide) que usas para escribir y trabajar con tu codigo. Estas programando en java.

Comment: gbianchi lo que quiero saber por ejemplo es si esta bien declarar el atributo semestre this.semestreAcademico = semestre; Osea semestre academico no es un atributo de tipo Primitivo sino mas bien un tipo de instancia de la clase semestre, al igual que programa y grupo

Comment: Para mi gusto, no. Semestre esta bien, pero quien deberia armar el semestre es la clase asignatura, deberia recibir todos los datos del semestre y armar los datos.. pero eso a mi gusto. Teoricamente estaria bien.

Comment: Has definido la composición correctamente, especificando los tipos de los componentes en los atributos y pasando objetos de esta naturaleza por argumentos al constructor. Cabe discutir quién es el compuesto y quién el componente, porque a mí personalmente me parece una solución igualmente válida que un **Grupo** esté compuesto de una o varias **Asignatura/s.** Ya sabes: la composición es una relación TIENE-UN (_Has-A_). Pero, como sabes también, la última palabra la tiene casi siempre tu jefe, tu cliente o tu profesor ;)